# How to extract the test results from testng.xml file using bash

Tags: xml, bash, shell, sh

I am trying to extract the test results from testng.xml file using shell commands

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testng-results skipped="0" failed="0" ignored="0" total="1" passed="1">
  ....................
</testng-results>
```

From the above the xml file I want to extract an output as

```
Total : 1
Passed : 1
Failed : 0
Skipped : 0
Failed : 0
```

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `xmllint` and `xpath` in a `shell`, with *variables*:

```bash
$ for str in total passed failed skipped; do
    xmllint --xpath "concat('${str^}: ', string(/testng-results/@$str))" file.xml
  done
```

```
Total: 1
Passed: 1
Failed: 0
Skipped: 0
```